# How to put navbar to the left with a fixed position

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an image album list made with framework-y and bootsrap, here is the link of what I'm using: http://html.framework-y.com/containers/masonry/#albums I have an album list that when clicked it opens images from that album, and shows in the top of the album a navbar that filters images with isotope.js, I need to make that navbar to the left and fixed, so it's always visible when scrolling down the images that would now be on the right, this only when watched in a pc when opened in a mobile or tablet I want to keep it the same way as it is now, on top as a list.

Thanks

UPDATE:

Code added, `<div class="navbar navbar-inner">` is the one that has the menu I need to relocate to the left.

```
         <div class="album-main" data-album-anima="fade-bottom">
                <div class="album-list row" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="album-box col-md-4" data-album-id="album-1">
                    <div class="img-box scale adv-img adv-img-half-content" data-anima="fade-left" data-trigger="hover">
                        <a href="#" class="img-box anima-scale-up anima" aid="0.1421574963962673" style="position: relative; transition-duration: 500ms; animation-duration: 500ms; transition-timing-function: ease; transition-delay: 0ms;">
                            <img alt="" src="/imagenes/galeria/categoria-1.jpg" class="loading" data-was-processed="true">
                        </a>
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h2 class="album-name">Breakfast</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>      
                <div class="cont-album-box">
                    <p class="album-title" style="display: block;">
                        <span>Breakfast</span>
                        <a class="button-list btn btn-border btn-xs">
                            <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i> Go Back                            </a>
                    </p>
                        <div class="album-item fade-bottom" style="display: block; transition-duration: 300ms; animation-duration: 300ms; transition-timing-function: ease; transition-delay: 0ms;">
                        <div class="grid-list" data-trigger="manual">
                            <div class="navbar navbar-inner">
                                <div class="navbar-toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i><span>Menu</span><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></div>
                                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" style="display: none; opacity: 1; height: 0px;">
                                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav over ms-minimal inner grid-filters">
                                        <li class="active current-active"><a data-filter="grid-item">All</a></li><li class=""><a data-filter="subcat-1">Homemade</a></li><li class=""><a data-filter="subcat-2">Kids</a></li><li class=""><a data-filter="subcat-3">Pork</a></li><li class=""><a data-filter="subcat-4">Machacado</a></li><li class=""><a data-filter="subcat-5">Omelettes</a></li><li class=""><a data-filter="subcat-6">Eggs</a></li><li class=""><a data-filter="subcat-7">Others</a></li><li class=""><a data-filter="subcat-8">Saturday and Sunday</a></li>                        <li class=""><a class="grid-order" data-sort="asc"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="grid-box row">  
                                <div class="grid-item col-md-4 subcat-1 row-20">
                                    <div class="advs-box advs-box-multiple boxed-inverse extra-content-cnt" data-anima="scale-rotate" data-trigger="hover" style="visibility: visible; opacity: 1;">
                                        <a class="img-box lightbox i-center" href="/imagenes/galeria/menu-1.jpg" style="opacity: 1;">
                                            <img class="anima loaded" data-src="/imagenes/galeria/menu-1.jpg" alt="" src="/imagenes/galeria/menu-1.jpg" data-was-processed="true" aid="0.7780172567376911" style="position: relative; transition-duration: 500ms; animation-duration: 500ms; transition-timing-function: ease; transition-delay: 0ms; opacity: 1;">
                                        </a>
                                        <div class="circle anima-rotate-20 anima" style="transition-duration: 500ms; animation-duration: 500ms; transition-timing-function: ease; transition-delay: 0ms;" aid="0.9083815830263298">$80<span>3 Pieces</span></div>
                                        <div class="advs-box-content" style="opacity: 1;">
                                            <h3>HOT CAKES</h3>
                                            <span class="extra-content">Includes 1 Orange Juice and Unlimited Coffee</span>
                                            <p>
                                                Hot Cakes con Jamón o Tocino o Cereal o Yogurt o Pan Tostado con Mermelada
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>  
                                <div class="grid-item col-md-4 subcat-1 row-20">
                                    <div class="advs-box advs-box-multiple boxed-inverse extra-content-cnt" data-anima="scale-rotate" data-trigger="hover" style="visibility: visible; opacity: 1;">
                                        <a class="img-box lightbox i-center" href="/imagenes/galeria/menu-2.jpg" style="opacity: 1;">
                                            <img class="anima loaded" data-src="/imagenes/galeria/menu-2.jpg" alt="" src="/imagenes/galeria/menu-2.jpg" data-was-processed="true" aid="0.2241172766887909" style="position: relative; transition-duration: 500ms; animation-duration: 500ms; transition-timing-function: ease; transition-delay: 0ms; opacity: 1;">
                                        </a>
                                        <div class="circle anima-rotate-20 anima" style="opacity: 1; transition-duration: 500ms; animation-duration: 500ms; transition-timing-function: ease; transition-delay: 0ms;" aid="0.08011167551452192">$53<span> </span></div>
                                        <div class="advs-box-content" style="opacity: 1;">
                                            <h3>MILK SHAKE</h3>
                                            <span class="extra-content"></span>
                                            <p>
                                                Vanilla - Chocolate - Strawberry
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>  <div class="grid-item col-md-4 subcat-1 row-20">
                                    <div class="advs-box advs-box-multiple boxed-inverse extra-content-cnt" data-anima="scale-rotate" data-trigger="hover" style="visibility: visible; opacity: 1;">
                                        <a class="img-box lightbox i-center" href="/imagenes/no-disponible-en.jpg" style="opacity: 1;">
                                            <img class="anima loaded" data-src="/imagenes/no-disponible-en.jpg" alt="" src="/imagenes/no-disponible-en.jpg" data-was-processed="true" aid="0.6266237997032682" style="position: relative; transition-duration: 500ms; animation-duration: 500ms; transition-timing-function: ease; transition-delay: 0ms; opacity: 1;">
                                        </a>
                                        <div class="circle anima-rotate-20 anima" style="opacity: 1; transition-duration: 500ms; animation-duration: 500ms; transition-timing-function: ease; transition-delay: 0ms;" aid="0.46139251079096577">$53<span> </span></div>
                                        <div class="advs-box-content" style="opacity: 1;">
                                            <h3>FRUIT SMOOTHIE</h3>
                                            <span class="extra-content"></span>
                                            <p>

                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
```

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a coding service. Please provide us with the code that you're working with and show us where you're stuck. We can then at least begin to debug and help you with your issue. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also, for the sake of clarity, I kindly request that you add some punctuation to your post as it's quite hard to follow.

Comment: @ProEvilz sorry! didn't mean to be rude.

Comment: Please see read the `minimal` part of the link I provided above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding `.pull-left`?

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inner pull-left">
```

To have it fixed you should use this as navbar markup:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
```

Comment: Yes, I created 2 columns, col-md-2 and col-md-10, added the .pull-left and it's perfect, now I'm wondering how to make it fixed, so when I scroll down I can see it?

Comment: You should search the bootstrap docs since this are very basic questions and they explain everything ...